# Using room in android to get changes in a table

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room to load data from a table and display it in an android application.

The number of lines in that table is huge however, so I cannot use LiveData to automatically trigger when the table changes and update my RecyclerView

what I am currently doing is, when at some point in my application a change is made (insert delete update) the repository keeps a list of all the changes made, and when I move back to the screen that shows those changes the viewmodel will compare the row ids with those loaded and update the ui as needed.

is there a better way to do this? like having a query with LiveData that will have a list of all the ids that are changed?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using LiveData with a ViewModel rather than manually keeping track of all changes to the repository and updating your UI.

What makes you think that you can't use LiveData because your database table is too big?  Are you getting some sort of error when you try?

When you use LiveData, you won't need to write a query that keeps track of which ids have been changed.  All of that is done by LiveData on a background thread and when any of the data that is being observed changes, the LiveData's observer is notified via an `onChanged()` method.

I found this tutorial for using LiveData with Room database really helpful:
https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47

Comment: well the table has millions of rows, so when I use livedata it takes about one or two seconds to get the results which is too long for a user to be looking at a blank screen, I can justify it once at the start but not every time a change is made, I know that I could be using the paging library, but at this point I can't for technical reasons

Comment: I see.  I guess you could implement your own paging if you don't want to use the paging library.  Just have the LiveData return an arbitrary page size and then fetch the next page when your recycler view requests a row you don't have.  There's some info here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/large-database-queries-on-android-cb043ae626e8

Comment: As an aside, mobile applications with millions of records are usually designed incorrectly.